# Rails scopes - do I use limit offsets or a scope for best performance?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, scope

I'm performing a number of queries and since the answers could be large, also batching requests and limiting the size of responses.  So logically I'm doing the following:

```
apply a filter to a set of entries
sort those entries by id
while there are more entries
    get the next 100 entries
```

The question is, what is the correct pattern for best performance.  The options I are to repeatedly query either:

```
Items.myFilter.sortById.idBiggerThan(<id-of-last-entry>).limit(100)
```

or

```
Items.myFilter.sortById.limit(<first-item-offset>, 100)
```

obviously tracking either id-of-last-entry or first-item-offset.

Is it possible to say which of the limits/offset options has the least impact on the DB server or is this a case of 'make the limit much bigger and time requests'?

And are there any things I can do to somehow cache Items.myFilter.sortById across requests?